# Apache Lucene TokenStream Filters

Tags: java, lucene, machine-learning

I have some questions regarding Apache Lucene Library:

1) How can I concatenate two TokenStream objects into one TokenStream object ?

2) Which filter can be used to remove all duplicate tokens (with same value) from a TokenStream object ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This sounds like a quite odd requirement to me. How did you end up with two TokenStreams in the first place? Couldn't you concatenate them at the source? And why would you eliminate duplicate tokens from textual content? Maybe you should rethink the way you map your domain into Lucene documents/fields?

Comment: I am using this tokenstream for classification purpose . I have two tokenstreams generated using NGramTokenizer for two different strings. If it's not possible to concatenate two TokenStreams into one object then I can just concatenate the two strings and pass it to NGramTokenizer. But my problem now, I want to remove duplicate tokens. For example, given this string "where are", using bigram NGramTokenizer I will have two tokens with the value "re". is there a filter in Lucene lib that can remove these duplicates ?

Comment: But what will it hurt if they stay there?

Answer (score 0):

As far as concatenating from two sources, just add two `Field` instances with the same name to the `Document`. This is guaranteed to be the same as a single field with the value concatenated.

As far as eliminating duplicated terms, this is not really necessary. Lucene will only count the term frequency for a document in order to score them higher. If you don't need that, you can define your own `Similarity` instance that implements `tf` as a constant of 1.

Or, if you need to disable term frequency per field only, you can instantiate the `Field` with `Field.TermVector.NO`.